# How to add installed program to the All Programs folder list in Wix Toolset

Tags: wix

I need help with the XML that adds the installed application to the `All Programs folder` in the start menu like in the picture above. I have written the xml that adds to the desktop but can't seem to find the one for start menu.

`This is the xml I used to add to desktop but I also want one for the All Programs Folder`

```
<DirectoryRef Id="DesktopFolder">
  <Component Id="DesktopShortcut" 
    Guid="{SOME-GUID}">

    <Shortcut Id="StartMenuShortcut"
        Name="!(bind.property.ProductName)"
        Target="[#MyApp]"
        WorkingDirectory="APPLICATIONROOTDIRECTORY" 
        Icon="Icon.ico" />

    <RemoveFolder Id="CleanUpShortCut" 
        Directory="DesktopFolder" 
        On="uninstall" />

    <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\[Manufacturer]\[ProductName]" Name="installed" Type="integer" Value="1" KeyPath="yes"/>
  </Component>
</DirectoryRef>
```

---

[image: Start Menu]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an example, you can do it by adding the following generic directory tags:

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">                                         <!--Mandatory base <directory> declaration.-->                                    
  <!--Specify the Program Menu Folder directory and Desktop folder for shortcuts-->
  <Directory Id="ProgramMenuFolder"  Name="All Programs folder">                    <!--%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\-->
    <Directory Id ="YourCompanyFolder1" Name="Your Company">                        <!--%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Your Company\-->
      <Directory Id ="YourCompanySubFolder1" Name="Sub Folder1">                    <!--%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Your Company\Sub Folder1\-->
        <Directory Id="YourAppFolder1" Name="YourAppFolder1"/>                      <!--%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Your Company\Sub Folder1\YourAppFolder1\-->
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Directory>
</Directory>
```

You can then use the "YourAppFolder1" as the directory reference for your application shortcut. A sample code to do that is as follows:

```
    <!--StartMenu Shortcut for YourApp-->
<DirectoryRef Id="YourAppFolder1">

  <Component Id="ApplicationStartMenuShortcut" Guid="USEYOUROWNGUID">
    <Shortcut Id="YourAppStartMenuShortcut"
              Name="YourApp"
              Description="YourApp description"
              Target="[INSTALLFOLDER]\YourApp.exe"
              WorkingDirectory="YourApp">
      <Icon Id="Icon" SourceFile="..\YourApp\Images\YourApp.ico"></Icon>
    </Shortcut>

    <RemoveFolder Id="RemoveYourCompanyFolder1" Directory="YourCompanyFolder1" On="uninstall" />
    <RemoveFolder Id="RemoveCompanySubFolder1" Directory="YourCompanySubFolder1" On="uninstall" />
    <RemoveFolder Id="RemoveYourAppFolder1" Directory="YourAppFolder1" On="uninstall" />
   <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\YourApp" Name="installed" Type="integer" Value="1" KeyPath="yes" />
</Component>
</DirectoryRef>
```

Answer (score 1):

@Tushortz [here](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/files_and_registry/create_start_menu_shortcut.html) you can find the steps to add installed programs to the All Programs folder aka Windows Start Menu, along with complete sample.